# Remove leading zeros in forecast period string

Tags: python, string, list, finance

I am needing to format forecast period columns to later merge with another data frame.

Columns of my data frame are:

```py
current_cols = [
    '01+11',
    '02+10',
    '03+09',
    '04+08',
    '05+07',
    '06+06',
    '07+05',
    '08+04',
    '09+03',
    '10+02',
    '11+01'
]

desired_out = [
    '1+11',
    '2+10',
    '3+9',
    '4+8',
    '5+7',
    '6+6',
    '7+5',
    '8+4',
    '9+3',
    '10+2',
    '11+1'
]
```

Originally, I tried to split the list by `split('+')`, and use `lstrip('0')` for each element in the list. Then recombine elements within tuple with `+` in between.

Is there a better approach? I'm having trouble combining elements in tuples back together, with `+` in between. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: _Show your code_ instead of describing what it is supposed to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re` module for the task:

```py
import re

pat = re.compile(r"\b0+")

out = [pat.sub(r"", s) for s in current_cols]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    "1+11",
    "2+10",
    "3+9",
    "4+8",
    "5+7",
    "6+6",
    "7+5",
    "8+4",
    "9+3",
    "10+2",
    "11+1",
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
current_cols =['01+11','02+10','03+09','04+08','05+07','06+06','07+05','08+04','09+03','10+02','11+01']
desired_out = []

for item in current_cols:

    if item[0] == "0":
        item = item[1:]

    if "+0" in item:
    
        item = item.replace('+0', '+')


    desired_out.append(item)
```

Comment: You can replace without checking that the substring is in the string, and it won't do anything if it isn't

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with nested comprehensions, conversion to `int()`, and formatting using an `f-string`:

```py
current_cols = [
    '01+11',
    '02+10',
    '03+09',
    '04+08',
    '05+07',
    '06+06',
    '07+05',
    '08+04',
    '09+03',
    '10+02',
    '11+01'
]

desired_out = [
    f'{int(a)}+{int(b)}' for (a, b) in [
        e.split('+') for e in current_cols
    ]
]
```

The code above will set `desired_out` with:

```
['1+11', '2+10', '3+9', '4+8', '5+7', '6+6', '7+5', '8+4', '9+3', '10+2', '11+1']
```

This method is implementing your original thought of splitting each element using the `+` signal as separator, extracting the leading zeros from each pair element (done with the `int()` conversion inside the `f-string`), and combining them back, with a `+` sign in between (also using the `f-string`).

The inner comprehension is just walking each element of the list, and splitting them by the `+` sign. The outer comprehension converts each element of each pair to `int()` to get rid of the leading zeros.

Answer (score 1):

We want a bunch of `map` operations here to do the following:

1. `split` each element of `current_cols` on `"+"`:
   `map(lambda s: s.split("+"), current_cols)`
2. `lstrip` the `"0"` out of each element of the resulting lists:
   `map(lambda l: (x.lstrip("0") for x in l), ...)`
3. `join` the resulting values on `"+"`:
   `map("+".join, ...)`

Then, we `list` out the elements of these `map` operations:

```
list(
     map("+".join, 
         map(lambda l: (x.lstrip('0') for x in l), 
             map(lambda s: s.split('+'), current_cols)
            )
         )
     )
```

which gives:

```
['1+11',
 '2+10',
 '3+9',
 '4+8',
 '5+7',
 '6+6',
 '7+5',
 '8+4',
 '9+3',
 '10+2',
 '11+1']
```